# Either John isn't stupid and he is lazy, or he is stupid. He's stupid; therefore he's not lazy. Why?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm reading How To Prove it by Daniel J. Velleman, and I came across the following example which sounds odd to me.

> Either John isn't stupid and he is lazy, or he is stupid.
>   He's Stupid.
>   Therefore he isn't lazy.

If we let S="John is stupid and L="John is lazy" then,
(¬S ∧ L) ∨ S.

I understand it if the OR is exclusive, but it doesn't explicitly say that. How does one arrive at the given conclusion?

Comment: Doesn't it have to be exclusive or since if both were true you would have S and neg S

Comment: The formulation with "either/or" clearly means an exclusive "or"

Comment: $S \to \neg(\neg S) \to \neg (\neg S \wedge L)$

Comment: See page 19 : "so the argument is invalid."

Comment: @peter - I still think it is wrong though - if John is 'stupid and Lazy' then clause 1 is false, but clause 2 is true - so the XOR condition is satisfied - as it can be if he is stupid and not lazy

Comment: @Cato Exactly what I say : The assumptions (and the XOR-statement is one of them) are correct, but the conclusion is wrong

Comment: A large portion of the world's population is both stupid and lazy. Just so you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given assumptions are not sufficient to conclude that John is not lazy.

If John is stupid and lazy, both assumptions are correct, but the conclusion is wrong.